# How to skip didReceiveFrame when there is already a new frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc

In a webrtc app there is a callback called didReceiveFrame, which is called when there is a new frame to be rendered. It passes the new frame as argument and one can extract a texture from this frame. However, if for some reason the main thread is delayed (think breakpoint, device rotation, still busy rendering, etc...) then this callback is called separately for every 'missed' frame. This effectively adds a delay between what the camera captures and what is rendered.

How can I make sure that didReceiveFrame is only called with the latest frame? Or how can I see if the passed frame is the latest (so I can skip the function)?

Answer (score 2):

I never found a way to do this with the library, but I implemented my own simple check using an `NSDate`. I store a property in the renderer class like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* timeOfLastFrame;
```

I initialise it in my `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
self.timeOfLastFrame = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0.0];
```

and I use it in my render method like this:

```
- (void)renderFrame:(RTCI420Frame*)frame {
    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timeOfLastFrame] > 1.0f/24.0f) { // or whatever fps you want
        self.timeOfLastFrame = [NSDate date];
        // do rendering
    }
}
```

The `1.0f/24.0f` part determines the max fps. In this case, it won't render more than 24 frames per second, which is pretty decent for a video stream and low enough to notice a performance increase. If the `renderFrame` method is called before 1/24th of a second has passed it simply doesn't do anything.

Note: Doing it like this means the rendering won't be at a steady 24fps, because it doesn't skip every x frames, instead it relies on when the render method is called and simply drops a frame if it came too soon after the previous one. I don't notice it in my app, but it's something to keep in mind, especially when using a low max fps.

Comment: You might want to provide a little commentary with your answer.

Comment: @Adrian Here you go ;)