# AppRTCDemo（webRTC） + iOS on iPhone 6 (iOS9) : Local RTCMediaStream is not working When I Set up the constraints

Tags: ios, webrtc

I use **pod 'libjingle_peerconnection', '~> 11142.2.0'**

When I Set up the constraints

```
NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[
                                  [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"320"],
                                  [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"240"],
                                  [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"15"]
                                  ];
RTCMediaConstraints* mediaConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
                                                                         optionalConstraints:nil];
```

and next

```
RTCAVFoundationVideoSource *source =
[[RTCAVFoundationVideoSource alloc] initWithFactory:_factory
                                        constraints:mediaConstraints];
localVideoTrack =
[[RTCVideoTrack alloc] initWithFactory:_factory
                                source:source
                               trackId:@"ARDAMSv0"];
```

or

```
RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:mediaConstraints];
localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];
```

then the result a "black" local stream. 
and also when i set

```
RTCMediaConstraints* constraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:nil
                                                                         optionalConstraints:nil];
```

It work properly；How can i created stream with some constraints ？

Answer (score 0):

This is my constraints initialisation code:

```
- (void) initMediaConstraints {
    if (!mediaConstraints) {
        // retrieve system information and set device name
        struct utsname systemInfo;
        uname(&systemInfo);
        NSString *deviceName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if ([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"] || [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"] || [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"] || [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"] || [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"]) {
            // use these constraints on crappy devices
            mediaConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[
                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"192"],
                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"144"],
                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"352"],
                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"288"]
            ]                                                        optionalConstraints:@[]];
        } else {
            mediaConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[
                [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"640"],
                [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"480"],
                [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"1280"],
                [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"760"]]
                                                                     optionalConstraints:@[]];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use them here:

```
- (void) initVideoSource {
    // create a capturer and video source
    if (!localVideoCapturer) {
        localVideoCapturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraId];
    }
    if (!localVideoSource) {
        localVideoSource = [peerConnectionFactory videoSourceWithCapturer:localVideoCapturer constraints:mediaConstraints];
    }
}
```

It detect if the app runs on an older iOS device and if it does, set lower constraints (I forgot which devices, but we tested pretty thoroughly on a wide range of devices to find these values). If it runs on a somewhat better device it sets higher resolution constraints (again we tested a lot to find these values).

As far as I know, max setting the max frame rate doesn't work with the native iOS library yet, at least it never did for me. Instead I implemented my own max fps check [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423847/how-to-skip-didreceiveframe-when-there-is-already-a-new-frame/37347480#37347480). This doesn't limit the amount of frames sent to the remote peer, but it does limit the amount of them that are rendered, which already greatly improves performance.

[For completeness' sake, here's my entire renderer and related view controller code](https://github.com/Kevin-Wessels/RTCViewController)

Comment: So when you want to provide mandatory constrains, optional constrains must be an empty array @[], not nil...